# AS3 Shared Object not flushing correctly and XML/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, actionscript-3

Hi all and thanks in advance for your help.

I have a quiz with 3 categories that uses shared object, and xml within php. I’m not grasping the shared object and xml aspect. The quiz works well if one player only plays. But if I set it to log out using externalinterface window.close then log in again it retains the scores from the round prior to the one the one just played. The actual scores are updating in the database just fine. But if the player logs back in the shared object hasn’t updated. It does so though if the browser if closed off for some time. I think then it is getting the data from the database and not the shared object.

So say... player 1 scores 200 in a new game ... totalscore is now 400. The score submits to the database. 
Player 1 logs out.
Player 2 logs in. Hasn’t played for awhile. The score from the database loads. 
Player 2 logs out.
Player 1 logs back in but the shared object score loads from before ie 200. Even though I (think) am loading the score using xml... and flushing the shared object before the scores submit to the database!

PHP looks like this...

```
 if ($todo == "login") { 

 $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM $nameTable WHERE userpass = '$userpass' 
 AND username = '$username' "); 

   if (!$result) { 
  $msg = ((is_object($connect)) ? mysqli_error($connect) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)); 
  $string = 'valid=0&err=error query'; 
   } else { 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)== 0) { 
        $string = 'valid=0&err=no result'; 

    } else { 


        header('Content-Type: text/xml'); 
        echo "<?xml version='1.0'?>"; 
        //echo "<".$nameTable.">"; 
            while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
            { 
             echo "<player>"; 

             echo "<username>".$data['username']."</username>"; 
             echo "<userpass>".$data['userpass']."</userpass>"; 
             echo "<userscore>".$data['userscore']."</userscore>"; 
             echo "<cat1>".$data['cat1']."</cat1>"; 
            echo "<cat2>".$data['cat2']."</cat2>"; 
            echo "<cat3>".$data['cat3']."</cat3>"; 

            }//end while 

        } //end if else result 

   } //end if else !result 
} //end if else login
```

AS3 login user is this...

```
         else if(e.currentTarget.name == "login_btn") 
    {
        var us:String = mc_now.loginuser.text;
        var pa:String = mc_now.loginpass.text;
        if(us.length > 0 && pa.length > 0 ) getXML(filePHP+"?todo=login&username="+us+"&userpass="+pa, "login");
        positioningInterface(login, 0, 0);
    }
```

LoadUser in AS3 is this...

```
function LoadUser(e:Event):void 
{
    trace("LoadUser: user is loaded")

    xmlLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadUser);

    myxml = new XML(e.target.data);

    //trace("len",myxml.username != undefined, myxml.length > 0);

    if(myxml.username != undefined) {

        positioningInterface(welcome, 0, 0);
        welcome.username_txt.text = myxml.username;
        welcome.msg1_txt.text = "Welcome Back";
        welcome.msg2_txt.text = "We hope you are enjoying playing this quiz!";
        welcome.displayscore.text = myxml.userscore;
        mySO.data.registered = isRegistered = true;


        nameActive = myxml.username;
        TotalScore = myxml.userscore;

        cat1 = myxml.cat1;
        cat2 = myxml.cat2;
        cat3 = myxml.cat3;

        mySO.data.cat1 = cat1;
        mySO.data.cat2 = cat2;
        mySO.data.cat3 = cat3;

        mySO.data.userSO = nameActive;
        mySO.data.TotalScore = TotalScore; /// TotalScore is the sum of the category scores

        mySO.flush();

        trace("LoadUser",mySO.data.userSO)  

    } else 
    {
        //if login failed, display login again, failed login text, clear text
        positioningInterface(login, 0, 0);
        login.loginuser.text = "Login Failed";
        setTimeout(function() {login.loginuser.text = "";login.loginpass.text = "";}, 1000);
    }
```

}

getSO and fillSO are correct I think. varSend is working properly submitting the scores. 
As said everything works well until the player logs out. I’ve tried clearing the shared object on log out so a new player can log in (works ok) but if the first player logs back after the 2nd player the SO for player 1 has not updated. The damn thing just won’t update the scores! There seems to be a delay of some sort. As said if the browser is closed and the player logs in, say, the next day then it’s loading the correct scores from the database.

I hope I’ve made sense. I don’t know what I’m doing wrong. This is driving me bonkers!!

Further info added if it's of help...

Shared Object is checked when the game first starts and when interfaces are initialised ...

```
    function checkingSO()
{

    if (mySO.data.registered || mySO.data.loggedOn)
    {
    isRegistered = mySO.data.registered = true;

    getSO();
    }

else
{
    trace("checkso: SO is empty");

    fillSO();
    }
}
```

Get the shared object ...

```
    function getSO()

{
    nameActive = mySO.data.userSO;

    cat1 = mySO.data.cat1;
    cat2 = mySO.data.cat2;
    cat3 = mySO.data.cat3;

    TotalScore = sumAllScore();

    trace("getso |", "register:",isRegistered,"name:",mySO.data.userSO, "points cat:",cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4,cat5,cat6, "tot:",TotalScore);        
}
```

And fill shared object ...

```
function fillSO()
{
    mySO.data.cat1 = cat1;
    mySO.data.cat2 = cat2;
    mySO.data.cat3 = cat3;

    TotalScore = sumAllScore();
    mySO.data.TotalScore = TotalScore;

    mySO.flush();

    trace("checkScore |", "register:",isRegistered,"name:",nameActive, "points cat:",cat1,cat2,cat3, "tot:",sumAllScore() ;     
}
```

As mentioned I find arrays really confusing. I had the categories in a split array which worked but I separated them because I don't know how to put an array inside an array. Akmozo's suggestion is what I have tried before and I think it's the correct thing to do for my problem. But am stuck!

Comment: Well... the 2 responses I've had so far are about correcting my grammar! I would put it to the jury that these 'editor's' have not as much experience as me in speaking nor writing English. Please cease and desist! I would like an answer to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with caching. Add a nocache-pseudo-var to your request:

```
getXML(filePHP+"?todo=login&username="+us+"&userpass="+pa+"&nocache="+Math.random(),"login");
```

Comment: Sadly that's not working Andre. It's getting the correct score from the database no problems so that part is fixed. But it's also clearing the data when a new round is played ie all the category scores and totalscore resets to zero when the user logs in and then plays a game. Anyone out there ... please please have spent weeks on this and I need a solution!

Comment: can you show the traces output please? Where is `mySO`  initialized?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using the same `SharedObject` for all your users, that's why your data is always overwritten. So to avoid that, you can use a `SharedObject` for every user, like this :

```
var users:Array = [
    {'_name': 'user_01', '_score': 123},
    {'_name': 'user_02', '_score': 567}
]

var my_so:SharedObject;

for(var i:int = 0; i < users.length; i++){

    var user_name:String = users[i]._name,
        user_score:Number = users[i]._score;

    my_so = SharedObject.getLocal(user_name);

    // if we have already saved data for the current user
    if(my_so.data.score){
        trace('user name : ', user_name, ', user score : ', my_so.data.score);
        // gives : 
        // user name :  user_01 , user score :  123
        // user name :  user_02 , user score :  567
    }
    // set data in our SharedObject
    my_so.data.score = user_score;

}
my_so.flush();
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you akmozo. Yes making an array makes sense. But how exactly to incorporate (or replace) that into the existing code? Am I to add your code to LoadUser? Sorry am a real noob.

Comment: Also, the thing that confuses me about arrays is when examples are given with data that is known eg you've given actual scores. But how to write the array when the data isn't known? Thx much for your help.

Comment: @WhizzBangQuizzes Here the most important is how to use SharedObjects, forget arrays, you don't need it in your code, I used it just to store my users.